# Prove there exists non-continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ that takes every value in $\mathbb{R}$ twice

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Exactly like in the title. First part of this question was to prove there is no continuous function with such a property, what I managed to prove. When it comes to the part from the title, I tried to construct such a function I took $\log(|t|)$ but then I realized it wont work if you have only vertical asymptotes because this function would span whole $\mathbb{R}$ twice, missing some points that need to be assign to something.It might be hard to construct such a function so now I suspect there might be some clever way to prove it indirectly.

Comment: Try a sawtooth function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function
$$f(x):=|x-2n| +n\quad \text{for $2n-1<x\leq 2n+1$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$}.$$
Its graph can be seen here: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20add((abs(x-2*n)%2Bn)*Heaviside(x-2*n%2B1)*Heaviside(-(x-2*n)%2B1),n%3D-3..3)).

It is easy to verify that $f$ attains each real number $y$ exactly twice:

1) if $y\not \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $f^{-1}(y)=\{\lfloor y\rfloor+y,
3\lfloor y\rfloor-y\}$;

2) if $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $f^{-1}(y)=\{2y-1,2y\}$.